# TextMeshPro doesn't change its text via PlayerMovement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a script to a cylinder, so I can move it using `W`,`A`,`S`,`D` and also make it jump using `SPACEBAR`. Also, I made the cylinder "run", when holding down `LEFT SHIFT`, and walk, when releasing it.

I also wanted to add a `TextMeshPro` text in front of the screen that specifies the current state of the cylinder (either WALKING or RUNNING). This is my `PlayerMovement.cs` script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public TextMeshPro State;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Session started.");
        State = GetComponent<TextMeshPro> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float groundDistance = 0.4f;

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f; 
        }


        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


        float g = -20f;
        float jumpHeight = 1f;
        float speed = 6f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            speed = 8f;
            State.text = "State: Running";
        }
        else {
            speed = 5f;
            State.text = "State: Walking";
        }

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * g);  
        }

        velocity.y += g * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

as you can see, I declared a `public TextMeshPro State;` and wanted to modify it in the `Update()` function. Whenever I run my game (also, it runs, but the text is not changed), the Console gives me the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerMovement.Start () (at Assets/PlayerMovement.cs:24)

My TextMeshPro item is called "State" and is attached to the Main Camera, which is attached to the cylinder. I can run my game, but nothing's happening to the text. Also, when I hold `LEFT SHIFT`, the cylinder doesn't move anymore. When I remove the line that modifies the text, the speed changes as it is intended to do.

What can I do to fix this? (Also, another problem, when the cylinder is on a certain ground, for example a Cube or a Terrain, and it looks down enough, the `State` text gets hidden behind that ground. How can this be fixed?)

If you need further information, please leave a comment and I'll edit my question as soon as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line with `State = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ();` and importing the necessary namespace (if not included)